# Place element just above on-screen keyboard in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8

How to place/position an element just above the on-screen keyboard in windows phone application (Silverlight - C#) so that it looks like a part of keyboard. Also need to consider automatic scrolling done by windows when the keyboard is above the focused element.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot put any control above the On Screen Keyboard in WindowsPhone, the On Screen Keyboard is a system object, you cannot access it.

Comment: By above I mean on top of it. Not in terms of z-index but in terms of position